# How to add Side header to primefaces datagrid?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid

I am trying to create following datagrid with primefaces

[image]

Please can anyone suggest which data component can work to get the above table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a panelGrid with your own styling:

[image]

```
        <p:panelGrid>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>HEADING1</p:column>
                    <p:column>HEADING2</p:column>
                    <p:column>HEADING3</p:column>
                    <p:column>HEADING4</p:column>
                    <p:column>HEADING5</p:column>
                    <p:column>HEADING6</p:column>
                    <p:column>HEADING7</p:column>
                    <p:column>HEADING8</p:column>
                </p:row>
            </f:facet>
            <p:row>
                <p:column styleClass="firstcolumn">TITLE1</p:column>
                <p:column/> <p:column/><p:column/><p:column/><p:column/><p:column/><p:column/>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column styleClass="firstcolumn">TITLE2</p:column>
                <p:column/><p:column/><p:column/><p:column/><p:column/><p:column/><p:column/>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column styleClass="firstcolumn">TITLE3</p:column>
                <p:column/><p:column/><p:column/><p:column/><p:column/><p:column/><p:column/>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
```

```
        <style>
        .ui-panelgrid-even, .ui-panelgrid-odd{
            border: 1px solid #ffffff;
            background:#88B147; 
        }
        .ui-panelgrid-header .ui-widget-header{
            background: #0C52CB;
            font-weight: normal;
            border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        }
        .ui-panelgrid .firstcolumn{
            background: #8BC1FF;
            color: #000000;
        }
        </style>
```

If you are showing data which is in a list on your bean it might be more appropriate with a [dataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml) though. But this you can style also, use firebug or similar to find the styles you need to overwrite.

Comment: Hi Jaqen H'ghar, thanks for the reply. But I'm not expecting this.  I want to create a datatable with top header and side header as well, which means the intersection of the top and side header will be the data which is dynamic in nature. I need to put a datagrid inside a panel grid. Is there any Idea with best alignment?